# error: no context exists with the name: "Aks_cluster_name" when tried from WSL

Tags: azure, azure-devops, kubernetes-helm, kubectl, azure-repos

I am trying to deploy a kubernetes pipeline from Windows Subsystem for Linux.

I am able to run these commands

```
az login
az account set --subscription Azure.NPE.Riviera
az aks get-credentials --resource-group RivieraRG --name RivieraAksCls0
```

When I run the below command

```
kubectl config use-context RivieraAksCls0
```

It gives me

```
error: no context exists with the name: "RivieraAksCls0"
```

How do I fix this issue?

(Note: I have all the permissions and able to run the above commands from Powershell)

Comment: try running `kubectl config get-contexts  -v6`, note the kubeconfig used(in the 1st line of the output) when running on powershell vs wsl. I suspect wsl is using different kubeconfig

Answer (score 4):

I have tested in my environment. The reason for the error is .kube/config file is created in the windows but not in the wsl. The .kube/config file needs to be copied to wsl.

Please use the below command to copy the config file from your windows machine to ubuntu.

```
cp /mnt/c/Users/[USERNAME]/.kube/config ~/.kube/config
```

Please refer below screenshot :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Run `kubectl config get-contexts` and if you see an empty list then your config file is not placed under correct folder.

You need to create your config file under `/home/<username>/.kube/`