# error: no context exists with the name: "default"

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline, azure-aks

Getting following error

```
Starting: Bash
==============================================================================
Task         : Bash
Description  : Run a Bash script on macOS, Linux, or Windows
Version      : 3.201.1
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash
==============================================================================
Generating script.
Formatted command: exec bash '/home/vsts/work/1/s/Orchestration/dev/deploy.sh'
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/bin/bash /home/vsts/work/_temp/bdf3cbe7-1e0a-4e19-a974-71118a3adb33.sh
error: no context exists with the name: "default"
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
Finishing: Bash
```

while I run the task from the azure pipeline

```
- task: Bash@3
    inputs:
      filePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Orchestration/dev/deploy.sh'
```

These are the contents of deploy.sh

```
kubectl config use-context default
kubectl apply -f Orchestration/dev/configmap.yaml
kubectl apply -f Orchestration/dev/secrets.yaml
kubectl apply -f Orchestration/dev/deployment.yaml
kubectl apply -f Orchestration/dev/service.yaml
```

I am not sure why there is an error, every azure aks cluster will have a default namespace, and I already have a default namespace

[image]

Comment: command `kubectl config use-context` is to select your cluster not the namespace

Comment: Please try to select the cluster name instead of `default`

Comment: error: no context exists with the name: "xxxxxx-aks"

Comment: no luck, still same error with cluster name

Comment: you need to authenticate to your cluster first: `az aks get-credentials`. see documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/aks?view=azure-cli-latest#az-aks-get-credentials. You will need a service connection with permissions on the cluster as well.

Answer (score 0):

`Agreed with @Thomas,`  The name which you have passed in  `kubectl config use-context default` . This is the type of namespace instead of that we need to provide name of cluster.

*For example to set the current context:-*

```
$ kubectl config use-context Context_name
```

Also Based on this [***Kubernetes docs***](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/#:%7E:text=Context,to%20communicate%20with%20the%20cluster.),

> **A context element in a `kubeconfig` file is used to group access parameters under a convenient name. Each context has three parameters:
> cluster, namespace, and user. By default, the `kubectl` command-line
> tool uses parameters from the current context to communicate with the
> cluster**

.

For more information please refer this **Kubernets Docs**| [***Configure Access to Multiple Clusters***](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/) .

*and this similar* **SO THREAD**|[***error: no context exists with the name: "Aks_cluster_name" when tried from WSL***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68960589/error-no-context-exists-with-the-name-aks-cluster-name-when-tried-from-wsl)

Comment: it given same error error: no context exists with the name: "xxxxxx-aks"